# How to access a variable inside of an if-statement

Tags: c, if-statement, variables, scope

This is a section of my function where if the scores were shifted (1) then it prints "Shift amount?" after and collects user input to be used in the `compute_total(earned,shifted, shift)` function:

```
printf("Were scores shifted (1=yes, 2=no)? ");
    double shifted;
    scanf("%lf", &shifted);
    if(shifted == 1){
      printf("Shift amount? ");
      double(shift);
      scanf("%lf", &shift);
    }else{}

    double total = compute_total(earned, shifted, shift);
```

However, obviously I cannot access the variable inside of the if-statement, when I bring the variable and scanf for shift outside of the if scope then the program will run but as I enter a digit for shift amount the terminal does not go any further through my program, it gets "stuck".

How should I solve this issue so I can access the variable but still function correctly?

Comment: Please provide some [mre] - some C code that *we* could compile! If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) as your compiler, read its documentation then invoke it with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. **Take inspiration from the source code of *existing* [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)**, like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/) or [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/).

Comment: Once your C program is compiled by GCC without warnings, use a debugger like [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program. Read also [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)

Comment: So instead of moving `scanf` outside the `if` just move the **variable declaration outside**. And possibly initialize it to 0.

Comment: Read carefully the documentation of each function you did not write, in particular [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) which can fail (and you did not check against that). Don't forget to use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) when relevant

Comment: BTW, your code can *use* a variable, or *call* a function (or some [*declared*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/declarations) function pointer).  The only variables you could call have a function pointer type. Read about [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) and look inside the source code of [GTK](http://gtk.org/) for examples.

Comment: I am confused, what is the problem? please elaborate

Comment: Just a hint, insert a blank as first character of the format string like `scanf(" %lf", &shift[ing]);`. It will consume the "enter" character left in the input stream, as any other whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You probbaly want this:

```
printf("Were scores shifted (1=yes, 2=no)? ");
double shifted;
double shift = 0;      // declare shift here (and probably initialize to 0?)

scanf("%lf", &shifted);
if(shifted == 1){
  printf("Shift amount? ");
  scanf("%lf", &shift);
}else{}

double total = compute_total(earned, shifted, shift);
```

BTW: `double(shift);` is wrong and doesn't even compile. Did you retype your code instead of copy/pasting it?